# Ruby regex replace

Tags: ruby, regex

how to replace this word

```
This is a _test_ on *regex* and other string manipulations. This is *crucial* for your *training*.
```

to be a

```
This is a <em>test</em> on <strong>regex</strong> and other string manipulations. This is <strong>crucial</strong> for your <strong>training</strong>.
```

Comment: What is the rule? Don't expect us to guess what you want.

Comment: markdown to html. Probably a gem that does this for you. If you want diy solution use regex with the `gsub` method.

Comment: the rules is using repacle using regex

Answer (score 1):

#tr doesn't use Regular Expressions to replace single characters, so if it doesn't necessarily need to use regex you could do something like this-

```
str = 'this _is_ a *string*'
new_str = []
# Split string into an array we can loop through
str.split.map do |word|
  # Trade the characters for blank strings, wrap in HTML
  if word.start_with?('_')
    new_word = "<em>#{word.tr('_', '')}</em>"
  elsif word.start_with?('*')
    new_word = "<strong>#{word.tr('*', '')}</strong>"
  end
  # Add the word to the new string
  new_word ? new_str << new_word : new_str << word
end
new_str.join(' ')
# => this <em>is</em> a <strong>string</strong>
```

Comment: how about using regex