# replacing word in sentence with regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I replace the Markdown formatting with HTML using Ruby regex:

```
hallo _html_ dan *gaga* sas *tes*
```

to be

```
hallo <em>html</em> dan <strong>gaga</strong> sas <strong>tes</strong>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby regex replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555955/ruby-regex-replace)

Answer (score 1):

There are allready gems for that, eg [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet)

Here an example where I use the default markdown renderer, but if you need diffferent syntax you can cook your own renderer.

```
require 'redcarpet'
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)
markdown.render("**This** _is_ an [example](http://example.org/).")
# => "<p><strong>This</strong> <em>is</em> an <a href="http://example.org/">example</a>.</p>"
```

In general it's a bad idea to use Regular Expressions with html or to reïnvent the wheel but if you insist, here a simple example how you could do that.

```
# create a hash with our regular expressions and replacements
map = { /_(.+?)_/ => '<em>\1</em>', /\*(.+?)\*/ => '<strong>\1</strong>'}
markdown = "hallo _html_ dan *gaga* das *test*"
# enumerate the hash and replace the expressions with their replacement
# tap returns the result to itself
markdown.tap{|md| map.each { |re, v|  md.gsub!(re, v)}}
# => hallo <em>html</em> dan <strong>gaga</strong> das <strong>test</strong>
```

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Hi Cary, I'm kind of a fan of you you know. Thanks for the suggestion, but why don't you answer this ? I felt like aiming at a moving target so I deleted it. Saw this just before going to sleep and I'm gonna call the day off.